# Cubic spline interpolation get coefficients

Tags: python, scipy, cubic-spline

Say I have two arrays in python and I wish to get (and actually use) the cubic spline interpolation between those points. (IE: I wish to integrate the function). I would strongly prefer a way using numpy scipy.

I know about [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html). However that only allows me to evalute the points, for say the very simply function of:

Now I could do something simply like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([0,2,3,4,8,10,12,12,12,10,9,8,7,1,0,0,1,2])
x = np.array(range(len(y)))
xvals = np.linspace(0, len(y)-1, len(y)*100, endpoint = False)
func = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
yvals = func(xvals)
plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.plot(x,y, "o")
```

However I wish to further process this cubic spline (ie I need to get the integration).. For manual doing things I need to get the factors, so:

```
a_i * x^3 + b_i * x^2 + c_i * x + d_i where i goes from 0 to n/3
```

(n = number of elemetns - this is just the definition of the ith cubic)

I hence expect a list of tuples (or 2d array) describing all splines. - Or a way to get the ith cubic, and really, really would love to get have a convenience "x-to-i" to find in which spline I am currently.

(Though of course this latter problem is a simple search for first value larger than reference in a sorted list - I could do that by hand easily if need be).

Comment: You could use `scipy.integrate.quad` to integrate the interpolated function.

Answer (score 1):

For interpolation, you can use `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(..., s=0)`.

It has, among other things, the [integrate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) method.

EDIT: `s=0` parameter to UnivariateSpline constructor forces the spline to pass through all the data points. The result is in the B-spline basis, you can get the knots and coefficients with `get_coefs()` and `get_knots()` methods. The format is the same as used in FITPACK, dierckx, on netlib. Note though that the tck format used internally by `interp1d` (which relies on `splmake` ATM) and `UnivariateSpline` (alternatively, `splrep`/`splev`) are inconsistent.

EDIT2: you can get a piecewise polynomial representation of a spline with [PPoly.from_spline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline) --- but this is *not* consistent with iterp1d. Use splrep(..., s=0) to get an interpolating spline, then convert the result.

Comment: The univariatespline is not a cubic spline, instead it is a so called 'b-spline', this is a complete different thing and has very very little to do with what I wish to achieve. - for one thing it doesn't do a curve fitting through the points. A cubic spline is defined as a series of 3rd order polynomials, each fitting two points, with the additional constraint that at each end point the splines have the same derivative.

Comment: interp1d with kind=cubic works in the b-spline basis as well. If you want a local interpolant in scipy, use BPoly.from_derivatives

Comment: Aren't splines usually built form b-splines?

Comment: @Dux those are two completelly different mathematical fields. cubic splines are a form of interpolation. b-splines a form of approximation. cubic splines WILL go through all points, B-splines will NOT guarantee that.

Comment: Of course you can express a cubic interpolating spline in the b-spline basis. @Dux see my edited answer.

Comment: @paul23: following up to the last comment, b-splines form a basis of splines, therefore, you can express a spline going through all data points in a b-spline-representation of a spline.

Comment: @ev-br - well then I actually need mathematical "proof" that those two are equal. - I can't see how they are, but that might be my limited knowledge. But I certainly can't use something without knowing under what circumstances the results are true. What is the mathematics governing the B-spline, and how does it fit up to the cubic splines. Like I said: I'm less interested in looks, but more so into it's mathematical quantities. (this spline will be used for further analysis such as integration and root finding)

Comment: @paul23 for proofs, see eg books of de Boor or Lyche or Schumaker

Comment: @paul23 if you want "proof", use `UnivariateSpline.derivatives(x)` to find the derivatives of the spline representation at point `x`. You can then check for yourself, integrate for yourself, and compare the results.

Comment: @Dux - that's just shows things, it is in no way mathematical sound - I honestly can't use that at all in a report, and I looked into it and I can't proof the functions myself either.

Comment: @paul23, i don't get what you want. If you want to have the cubic coefficients, you can easily calculate them from the derivatives. I can submit an answer that shows you how, if you want. If you want the spline representation, you can get them from `.get_coefs` and calculate it from the b-spline basis. I suggest you look up wikipedia on b-splines for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought that might help.  [From the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx), you can get a cubic spline interpolation in a different way which may help you:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([0,2,3,4,8,10,12,12,12,10,9,8,7,1,0,0,1,2])
x = np.array(range(len(y)))
xvals = np.linspace(0, len(y)-1, len(y)*100, endpoint = False)
func = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)
yvals = scipy.interpolate.splev(xvals, func, der=0)

# display original vs cubic spline representation for security...
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', xvals, yvals, x, y, 'b')
plt.legend(['Linear', 'Cubic Spline'])
plt.axis([-0.05, 20, -2, 20])
plt.title('Cubic-spline interpolation')
plt.show()
```

This gives you access to coefficients should you want via

```
pp = scipy.interpolate.spltopp(func[0][1:-1],func[1],func[2])

#Print the coefficient arrays, one for cubed terms, one for squared etc
print(pp.coeffs)
```

It also gives an example on the page of how to integrate using this cubic spline representation (changed the constant to suit your situation, I hope - your mileage may vary):

```
def integ(x, tck, constant=0):
    x = np.atleast_1d(x)
    out = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
    for n in xrange(len(out)):
        out[n] = scipy.interpolate.splint(0, x[n], tck)
    out += constant
    return out

const_of_integration = 0
yint = integ(xvals, func, const_of_integration)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`scipy.signal.cspline1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cspline1d.html) returns the coefficients of the b-spline terms with mirror-symmetric boundary conditions. It is useful if you need to perform additional filtering in the coefficients