# How to get the coefficients returned from interp1d in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

Using  [iterp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) from scipy you can fit a cubic to some data. But how do you get the coefficients of the cubic polynomial that you have just fitted?

As a trivial example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = [1, 2, 3.5, 4] 
y = [2, 3, 4, 5] 
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458589/cubic-spline-interpolation-get-coefficients
check if this answers your question

Comment: The only Method listed for the class is _call_, so, no, there is no way to get into the guts of the class without going into the source code. InterpolatedUnivariateSpline may be a way to approach things, or one of the other scipy.interpolation functions.